# How is the number of shorted shares for a given company publicly known?

Tags: short-selling

I wonder how the number of shorted shares for a given company is publicly known. For example, http://www.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3062-nasdaqshort-highlites.html ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20171102011837/http://www.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3062-nasdaqshort-highlites.html)) indicates the percentage of the float that is shorted  :

[image]

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment. But does https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/60760 answer your question?

Comment: @user52144 thanks, it does to some extent, hopefully someone will clarify what happens on the US market.

Comment: Can you provide a link to that page?  Thanks

Comment: @BobBaerker https://web.archive.org/web/20171102011837/http://www.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3062-nasdaqshort-highlites.html